# Finding the power sandwich

Tags: code-golf, math, integer

## Introduction

Finding the *closest* power to a number is a common enough problem. But what if you need both the next-highest and next-lowest power? In this challenge you must find the closest powers to a given number - the 'power sandwich' if you will, where the given number is the filling and the powers are the bread. Mmm, tasty.

## Challenge

Given a power **P >0** and a number **N >0**, output the largest integer **x^P** that is smaller or equal to **N**, and the smallest integer **y^P** that is greater or equal to **N**.

Input should be taken as a list of two positive (>0) integers, first the power P and then the number N. Output should be a list of two integers, the first being smaller or equal to N, the second being greater or equal to N, and both being a power of P.

If N is a power of P already, the output should be the list [N, N].

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code (as measured in bytes) wins.

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> [2, 17]

Output:

> [16, 25]

Explanation: 16 is the biggest square number (power of 2) less than or equal to 17, and 25 is the smallest square number greater or equal to 17.

## Test cases

```
[2, 24] -> [16, 25]
[2, 50] -> [49, 64]
[3, 8] -> [8, 8]
[1, 25] -> [25, 25]
[3, 25] -> [8, 27]
[4, 4097] -> [4096, 6561]
[2, 10081] -> [10000, 10201]
[11, 2814661] -> [177147, 4194304]
[6, 1679616] -> [1000000, 1771561]
```

Comment: I think the output for the last test case should be `[ 1000000, 1771561 ]`. Nice first challenge, anyway!

Comment: @Arnauld Nice spot, thank you! Corrected.

Comment: I think a more interesting challenge might be to find the sandwich without restricting p.

Comment: I think you mean both outputs should be a Pᵗʰ power.

Comment: @Jonah No, the challenge says that both outputs are a power of P, which is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Jonah I think Neil's comment was just for the OP. It's completely unrelated to your suggestion. (The challenge does indeed mention "power of P", which is wrong.)

Comment: @Jonah I made the challenge that you proposed: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266293/finding-the-power-sandwich-version-2

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7), 39 bytes

Expects `(p)(n)`.

```javascript
p=>n=>[x=(q=n**(1/p)|0)**p,(q+=x<n)**p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9LbsIwEIb3PYWXduo2M854bEs1F0EsEIWKCjmhIMSid09tUyGRMKtZfP/re31ZnzY/@@H8lvrP7biL4xAXKS6W1yiPMTWNxHZQv6CaZtDy@BqvH6n8q3HTp1N/2L4f@i@5k0ZJQ0qJ27WtWCJrYezqZcZZeOAoaME05Tol/R2rnNfCTynMqfbBzdhnqd2My27GTTFSkiC4f7CWg5BnsGV8MgQBPN7gOhjyaYFgYEZjaeqRmIug0s4hOS0IA3Uw28/Znl1g5BJwt68BWVkKjX8)

#### Alternate version (same size)

```javascript
p=>n=>[0,1].map(i=>(n--**(1/p)+i|0)**p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc/PboMwDAbw@54ix4SGYgfHSQ7wIlUPqH8mqhaiddpp785COlUq1Oefv8@@dD/d/fDVx@9yGI@n6dxMsWmHpt2Bxv321kXZN60cyrIoJFZRbfpfUEUR1XQYh/t4PW2v46c8S6OkIaXEY6pK7JC1MHb/sXIWXhwFLZiWrlbSP1l2Xgu/VJha7Uuase9a65VLacYtGSlJENw/zMdBSG@wZXzzCAJ4fOD8MKTRAsHASuN8qUdinheydg7JaUEYqIbV/5zi2QVGngue8bkgbc4HTX8)

Comment: Fail `3,64` due to float precision

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```r
\(P,N)abs(c(r<-N^(1/P),-r)%/%1)^P
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY9BDsIgEEX3ngJjmkBCU4YOAyTqEZru1SZq0gNUPY2bauKhvIRnECg1smF48-f_4f4Yxme_ed2ufeneyz1vZSOOpws_82FdNh2HqhWyHERRFSC6Ngs_PdeSaRQrVm7ZDig8zGGRqFGZopeMMNJaMpehC2VEECcy02Yer_9oUGobIUqGytvZVfmQRoYg54FSDuZFVDgRaZXaEGMcINFPYS2gDY7gsVZpu2AHZD0B_bsknyCOQdOvx3G6vw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
Ėe₍⌊⌈$e
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLElmXigo3ijIrijIgkZSIsIiIsIjFcbjI1Il0=)

Trivial implementation.

```
Ėe₍⌊⌈$e­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
Ėe       # ‎⁡Exponentiate N with the reciprocal of P
  ₍⌊⌈    # ‎⁢Pair results of floor, ceil in a list
     $e  # ‎⁣Swap (returns first input) and exponentiate with P
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 46 bytes

*based on port of [Arnauld's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266255/finding-the-power-sandwich/266257#266257)*

```python
lambda p,n:[int(q:=n**(1/p))**p,(-(-q//1))**p]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY39XISc5NSEhUKdPKsojPzSjQKrWzztLQ0DPULNDW1tAp0NHQ1dAv19Q3BvFiornkFRSC1aRpGOkYmmppcCK6CqQES31hHwQKJa6ijYGSKKo3CN9FRMDGwNEc10NDAwMIQ2RCQKRaGJmZmyKJmQIVm5pZmhmZAQYgrFyyA0AA)

`floor` and `ceil` of p-th root to the power of p

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)

```
(⌊⋈⌈)∘√´⋆⊑
```

Try it [here.](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgKOKMiuKLiOKMiCniiJjiiJrCtOKLhuKKkQoK4oCiU2hvdyBGIFsyLCAyNF0K4oCiU2hvdyBGIFsyLCA1MF0K4oCiU2hvdyBGIFszLCA4XQrigKJTaG93IEYgWzEsIDI1XQrigKJTaG93IEYgWzMsIDI1XQrigKJTaG93IEYgWzQsIDQwOTddCuKAolNob3cgRiBbMiwgMTAwODFdCuKAolNob3cgRiBbMTEsIDI4MTQ2NjFdCuKAolNob3cgRiBbNiwgMTY3OTYxNl0KCkA=)

Explanation:

```
(⌊⋈⌈)∘√´⋆⊑ # tacit function which takes a list [P,N]
 ⌊⋈⌈       # take the floor paired with the ceil
(   )∘√´   # of the P-th root of N
        ⋆⊑ # and raise to the power P
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), 51 bytes

```
f(l)=[floor(l[2]^{1/l})^l[1],ceil(l[2]^{1/l})^l[1]]
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/c7wznzknjm) Expects list `[p,n]` and returns list `[x^p,y^p]` as per specifications.

Explanation:

```
f(l)=[                      ,                     ]    Given a list, return a list
      floor(l[2]^{1/l})^l[1]                           floor(n^1/p)^p
                             ceil(l[2]^{1/l})^l[1]     ceil(n^1/p)^p
```

Comment: You can definitely save some bytes by putting `l[2]^{1/l}` into a wackscope variable, along with putting `^l[1]` outside the list to take advantage of Desmos's broadcasting. But at that point, that starts to converge towards my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
*İ}Ḟ,ĊƊ*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/ryIbahzvm6RzpOtal9f/wcgd9b83I//@juaKNdBSMTGJ1wAxTAxDDWEfBAkQbAmVMoQIQhomOgomBpTlUtaGBgYUhWCFIpYWhiZkZmGsGlDIztzQzNAPyYgE)

Profoundly boring direct floor-ceil solution. However, if the N-is-a-power-of-P case can be relaxed to permit outputting just `[N]`...

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
*İ}¹ị*€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/ryIbaQzsf7u7WetS05v/h5Q763pqR//9Hc0Ub6SgYmcTqgBmmBiCGsY6CBYg2BMqYQgUgDBMdBRMDS3OoakMDAwtDsEKQSgtDEzMzMNcMKGVmbmlmaAbkxQIA)

...we actually have a builtin for floor-ceil. Namely, the index-into dyad `ị`.

```
*İ}        Pth root of N.
   ¹       (Break undesired initial 2,2,2 chain.)
    ị      Index that into
     *€    the list of x^P for all x <- 1..N.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 37 bytes

```
f(p,n)=[floor(k),ceil(k)]^p
k=n^{1/p}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cg5g5ud8t2?nographpaper)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zygbhr2gee?nographpaper)

The best I could think of for now.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
zmDî‚ï¹m
```

Port of [*@AidenChow*'s Desmos answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266310/52210).

Inputs in the order \$P,N\$.

[Try it online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m73MwDQxyTB1wYKlpSVpuhZrq3JdDq971DDr8PpDO3OXFCclF0NlFiwx4jI0h7AB) or [verify all test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m73MwDQxyTB1wYaySnslhUdtkxSU7CsTig-tXFpakqZrsbYq1-XwukcNsw6vP7Qud0lxUnLxQh2I1IKbYdHRRjqG5rE6QMrIBEyZGgApYx0LIGmoY2QK5oApEx0TA0uIUkMDAwtDkAKgCgtDEzMzEMdMx9DM3NLM0Cw2FmI8AA).

**Explanation:**

$$[N_a,N_b]=\left[\left\lceil N^\frac{1}{P}\right\rceil,\left\lfloor N^\frac{1}{P}\right\rfloor\right]$$

```python
z         # Push 1/P, where P is the first (implicit) input-integer
 m        # Take N to the power this 1/P, where N is the second (implicit) input-integer
  D       # Duplicate it
   î      # Ceil the copy
    ‚     # Pair the two together
     ï    # Floor/cast both to integers
      ¹m  # Take both values in the pair to the power P
          # (after which the resulting pair is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
ＮθＮη≔¹ζＷ‹Ｘζθη≦⊕ζＩＸ⟦⁻ζ›Ｘζθηζ⟧θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCsIwFEX3fkXGPIiDilMncZCCle7iEOPDBNrXNi@x0J@PKXYQx3M55xqrvel1m1JFQwzX2D3QyxHK4pdt5iOze5HcKjFnmqxrUcgLMsumn7IzKzGCEhZA1HpY7YqMxw4p4PPbNd5RkCfNYc1utaPIS332qENe/u9yeF8AoExpX@wOafNuPw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `P` and `N`.

```
≔¹ζ
```

Start with `y=1`.

```
Ｗ‹Ｘζθη≦⊕ζ
```

Increment `y` until it is large enough.

```
ＩＸ⟦⁻ζ›Ｘζθηζ⟧θ
```

Output the `P`th powers of `x` and `y`.

61 bytes for a more efficient version:

```
ＮθＮη≔¹ζ≔¹εＷ‹Ｘεθη≦⊗εＷ›⁻εζ¹«≔÷⁺εζ²ιＦ¬‹Ｘιθη≔ιεＦ¬›Ｘιθη≔ιζ»ＩＸ⟦ζε⟧θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY89C8IwFEXn9ldkTKAOVpycREEKtnQXh6jRPoiJTdIWKv72@Irxo4vDGy7ccw/vWHFz1Fx6n6lb44rmehCG1mwR/@YK89JauCg6TUg/SgJTV4EUhG6FtbTUHRIiITVLSMUYyfkttNe6OUhxGjEbI7hDIAfV2AHrEZsido@jgGXKraGFk6Cl/HZSPMCd6KwNoYV2v3r46BkJK/DSfutv8z9iePURlwaUoytuXSjvehzbDwRjC@9ncTr3k1Y@AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `P` and `N`.

```
≔¹ζ≔¹ε
```

Start with both `x` and `y` equal to `1`.

```
Ｗ‹Ｘεθη≦⊗ε
```

Double `y` until it is large enough.

```
Ｗ›⁻εζ¹«≔÷⁺εζ²ιＦ¬‹Ｘιθη≔ιεＦ¬›Ｘιθη≔ιζ»
```

Perform a binary search to narrow down the range of `x` and `y`.

```
ＩＸ⟦ζε⟧θ
```

Output the `P`th powers of `x` and `y`.

19 bytes using floating-point arithmetic:

```
Ｎθ≔ＸＩη∕¹θηＩＸ⟦⌊η⌈η⟧θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05rLsbg4Mz1PIyC/HCjgnFhcopGhqaPgklmWmZKqYaijUKgJ5GYAFQYUZeaVQFRAFEe75eTnF4GVO6dm5mTmpQPZsWAdmtb//xtzGZn@1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `P`.

```
≔ＸＩη∕¹θη
```

Take the `P`th root of `N`.

```
ＩＸ⟦⌊η⌈η⟧θ
```

Output the `P`th powers of the floor and ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>25</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
{0\{@@).2$?.-1$<}do@;@}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlf97/aIKbawUFTz0jFXk/XUMWmNiXfwdqh9n9dgULBfxMFEwNLcwA)

I’m pretty sure this method is optimal, considering GolfScript doesn’t have floats and thus no min/max. <s>It’s possible that there’s a shorter way to do the stack manipulation, but that seems pretty unlikely to me at this point.</s> I stand corrected (by myself)—I was able to get rid of the variable `i`. Now I think this is optimal…but then I’ll probably find another 1-byte save somewhere else

This is a block (function) taking N then P on the stack and leaving the two values on top of the stack.

Explanation:

| Code | Stack (bottom to top) |
| --- | --- |
| `{…}` Block | `2 17` |
| `0\` | `2 0 17` |
| `{…}do` Run until result is 0… | Showing first pass over: |
| `@@` Stack shift | `17 2 0` |
| `)` Increment | `17 2 1` |
| `:` Duplicate | `17 2 1 1` |
| `2$` Push third from stack | `17 2 1 1 2` |
| `?` Exponentiate | `17 2 1 2` |
| `:` Duplicate | `17 2 1 2 2` |
| `-1$` Push bottom of stack | `17 2 1 2 2 17` |
| `<` Less than? | `-1 2 1 2 0` |
| (pop and either repeat or stop) | `17 2 1 2` |

At the end of the loop, the stack looks like `17 1 4 9 16 2 5 25` so we do `@;@` to make the top of the stack be `25 16`.

It took like twenty minutes of fiddling around to get the stack manipulation to work right.

Comment: When the input is already a perfect power then the output needs to be two copies of the input, e.g. the `3, 8` example.

Answer (score 1):

## [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 79 bytes

```cs
(p,n)=>(Math.Pow(Math.Pow(n,1d/p)is{}x?(int)x:x,p),Math.Pow(Math.Ceiling(x),p))
```

Alternate approach that uses 87 bytes

```cs
(p,n)=>{var(i,x)=(0,0d);for(;(x=Math.Pow(++i,p))<n;);return(Math.Pow(x==n?i:~-i,p),x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVPfT9swEH7vX3GKJmFrJsQhTVu6ghCFiY1JaEXbw9hDSNzirYtD40CqKH97d3boT3VI80PO9nf33ee7S5wfxrlcXBVp/EGmmoH9kEQVD1PBoLH0FMYwWJCMpXRwSr5E@tG9VS/rTcp4cpRRmVd1eUaQgpYnJcso23a9EHIq0wkpKWJ00W@1bF6yTEz3ZZ7AAEoYoARSutda/OEMmo1PkaH1HM1Ai1yjWypeYChjLVUazeZv8xLaqlqAqwLiM@Ad48RDBn6bQs02ID/4J9T2DBT0GITBJnTMoGuQrrEb99xyIOC3d9mOlxDG@J1NJGAQeD2rDy3KCNsh3xHCPa/LrUwPlzn73pYPN6m7PAjDxq3T4UEHiXkvOPa2tGMCHnZ6IQ9XfJYRI5q8rRrL/qxkAspU@MdPyKnpz2ieY1PcoYwmqcq1jHN3KB6Kift9JrW4kakguZ5h/91PSqbkgB0wjMQeWq6MqIdfItb/QWbab0SbCciiPBcJzoDXt3djNRNR/AjEgL@fMxwDOyW0eab9LmNFmWEgOrnfomkh@itwd2hgovQabR5jM68v9Wy@2q@zmIWxmGVCTJ7PYk77W@ir/vcD4@dePhXRNCcojMIZcDhZPmvTHfb5Orfno5GDAc7V@fWNs46qV7s40qYwl2UsMvOrgKBvSk7EOCqmmuxWg@6VJNyPQt/NM0Goe6dGtkaE7tNxodJcTcVGR985Y1K91qemcAiVIa2BoJATuHcqtPW9w0zH7Bktnqnzyt9w7@M1VbkcNnwiqY8qMwvuhSpSXS@jl3FfRZTYMLxf/AU)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+ WIN, 18 bytes

Prompts for power and integer:

```
((⌊p),⌈p←⎕*÷n)*n←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv4bGo56uAk2dRz0dBUBRoKzW4e15mlp5EM5/oCKu/2lcRlxGJlxASoHL1ABIG3NZAElDLiNTMAdMmXCZGFiagxRxGRoYWBiCFABVWBiamJmBOGZchmbmlmaGZgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
w1Y\^tkwXkh1G^
```

[Try on MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=w1Y%5C%5EtkwXkh1G%5E&inputs=6%0A1679616&version=22.7.4) or
[Test all cases](https://tio.run/##TYyxDoIwFEX3fsVNjFujfVgeZXJxJE4OtViimwbdmoAD315bNYS3nXvufa9beMbrA0G4I/YYsYEAMMFNeINgm5St7SqHPg50vnShH2x/p6aL9gA34pREW0gU2uN7IlOpZtpJmD8kotQsl25BWkKruvLzF1LKkP/t8tCQZiYvWk6Oq5qJPYTaqg8)

```
w    % Get both inputs and bring P to the top of the stack
1Y\  % Take the inverse of P
^    % Raise N to that power i.e. take N's P-th root
tk   % Take a copy of that root and floor it
wXk  % And ceil the original copy
h1G^ % Raise both those values to the power of P
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 7 bytes

```
ė*∦⌊⌈$*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLElyriiKbijIrijIgkKiIsIiIsIjExXG4yODE0NjYxIiwiMy4xLjAiXQ==)

Takes two integers as its argument and returns two integers. Works the same as various other answers including [@mathscat’s Vyxal one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266261/42248) and [@UnrelatedString’s Jelly one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266269/42248).

### Explanation

````
ė*∦⌊⌈$*
ė       | Reciprocal of n
 *      | To the power of p
  ∦⌊⌈   | Pair ceiling with floor and wrap in a list
     $* | To the power of p

```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```rust
|p,n:f64|{let x=n.powf(1./p);(x.floor().powf(p),x.ceil().powf(p))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPLjtowFN3zFR4WyKmCG4cQIFNG6gdUXVQaVYoQygRnsOo4aewMtJBvp9cOaYChqhexde55XD9S1UqfyvoFZRLlCZfYQeMnBN/DAMEQTKM3tESnY@nKKAuD48FA@6UkZbHLMCUfS@cR70kmiqLCTouWjrsnKeOiB5zm9PjXUekNl@AKcxTxIoosgJ2ekdcavdRZxiqgfdMVl69RJNmu4@y2XDDL/PoDmiBLa1Ur/ptF0ZfP353WnUtSsWSzFlwyPOpNu@11caYOirZIIC7vgszgmSUQrtYsL/UvfCk3Iy2k5rJmvaS5si@TSqsIPbP00/oJcqybKgXXeDh@GjokT0p8VEekztkxbEkRweBMxv6K6GKt7BlgxyFpIQRLtWnwqkPIibksa@2yfQkEtllB1OiDDb9p@F5TVtt15d5p6p9tXDq/i8HwcJwIYXg7LoKPuRlss2NvRWChGFjXcldBnOO2bcX0fem/QaLYuVv@ujUJbxCL5I3EsCqmaqGBkRVVnugHPDxExGtcZKehi4wLsjbX4hI2roUEQXxoVuYnMTMI2jNHo9b5RpUoxSq9Zj8fcHcr96j9czk/wVSwpOrOthk0p9h3kR@0uTSE9XQ1MNjUa7Fg4aIwAGzionkLzc1qEFNLtog/PQsnPQYsfwYQ3E7gLWZnN28BGeE0pG0K9bw5PYd7MAzie6ZIjf2cBmHY1WczGszAjC6CiWc6AicazhYhDS8crAdQTcQf)

Trivial implementation: takes `n` to the power of `1/p`, and then calculates `floor` and `ceil` to the power of `p`.

Takes the integer inputs as 64-bit floats and returns its output as a tuple of 64-bit floats.

*-1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

Comment: @ceilingcat thanks, I completely missed that one